# How can I cast java.lang.Number[] to java.lang.Byte[]?

Tags: java, arrays, numbers

I'm playing around with the Number wrappers of Java and I got the following error when I tried to cast a Number[] to Byte[]:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    Cannot cast from Number[] to byte[]
    Type mismatch: cannot convert from byte[] to Byte[]
```

The code it breaks on is:
    Byte[] coordinates;

```
ByteVector(Number... coordinates) {
    super(coordinates);
    this.coordinates = (Byte[])coordinates;
}
```

How can I write this so that I can input an array of any kind of Number and cast it to an array of Byte?

The constructor is called with `new ByteVector(1,2);`, so

Comment: you want to convert `Number[]` to `byte[]` right?

Comment: I can't cast to byte[], since it's a primitive type, so I thought I would be able to cast it to it's wrapper class.

Comment: have you looked at using `Number.byteValue() `?  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html#byteValue()

Comment: What you want to achieve? What happens when `BigDecimal` will be passed as parameter?

Comment: @Friso1990 what do you finally want `Byte[]` or `byte[]`?

Comment: `byte[]` is not a primitive type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot cast arrays for a simple reason: It is not safe. Example

```
Number[] numbers = new Number[10];
numbers[0] = new Byte(10);
numbers[1] = new Byte(11);
Byte[] bytes = (Byte[]) numbers;
numbers[2] = new Double(0);
```

So if this were allowed, there would now be a Double in the Byte[] - can't happen! And this is actually true the other way too:

```
Byte[] numbers = new Byte[10];
numbers[0] = new Byte(10);
numbers[1] = new Byte(11);
Number[] bytesNumbers = (Number[]) numbers; // upcast - still not safe!
bytesNumbers[2] = new Double(0);
```

Comment: So if I want to go from the Numbers array to  Bytes array I would need to create the Bytes array desperately first and then cast each individual Number to a Byte into the Byte array?

Comment: @Friso1990 Yup. That's the way to do it

Answer (score 0):

`Number` is `Serializable`, so you could simply serialize your array.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Java 8 Stream API to iterate over the array, convert each number to byte and collect to array:

```
this.coordinates = stream(numbers)
    .map(Number::byteValue)
    .toArray(Byte[]::new);
```

`stream` method is staticly imported `java.util.Arrays.stream`.

Note that you might lose precision here. For example if `numbers` contains `12345` it will be converted to `57`. Four doubles and floats, all decimal parts will be lost.